# Hover image wont' fix the size of the caption

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a sliding hover effect.

However I am stuck with the size of the images.
1. The image won't just fill up the whole box it seems that there is a space on the right side
2. The caption won't center on the screen

here's my markup:

```
<ul>

<li>
     <ul class="slide moveup">
        <li>
            <h2>This is a cool title!</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
        </li>

        <li><img class="top" src="http://feelgoodburtonsnowboard.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/01.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li>
     <ul class="slide moveup">
        <li>
            <h2>This is a cool title!</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
        </li>

        <li><img class="top" src="images/01.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    </ul>
</li>


<li>
     <ul class="slide moveup">
        <li>
            <h2>This is a cool title!</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
        </li>

        <li><img class="top" src="http://feelgoodburtonsnowboard.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/01.jpg" alt=""/></li>
    </ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

Here's the JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/bbpw33db/2/

Any idea?

Comment: Images are unreachable in the Fiddle (but that may be related to my professional network)

Comment: Sorry updated link here: http://jsfiddle.net/bbpw33db/2/

Answer (score 0):

Image is smaller than the list width. So, use `width: 100%;` for the image:

```
.moveup img {
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out 0s;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbpw33db/10/).

---

Updated as per your comment :) <sup>oops I forget about that</sup>

```
.slide.moveup > li:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bbpw33db/17/)

Comment: Won't that crop the image?

Comment: No. It won't, but stretch the image.

Comment: Is there any way that we can still have it perfectly fit without the image being stretch?

Comment: Then, you need to use background-image instead of `<img />`

Comment: If you inspect the image, you'll see that a part of it is extended to the bottom. However, if you add also `height: 100%`, then it looks good.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You also need to use `height: 100%`

Comment: How can I center the text caption? It seems that It can be centered. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the CSS for .moveup img

```
.moveup img {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -15px;
    width: 100%; /*Fit the image to its container. the aspect ratio is preserved; the image will not be distorted*/
    -webkit-transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: top 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

And the pseudo hover class to:

```
.moveup img.top:hover {
        top:-114%; /*set to a value to hide the whole image*/
        padding-bottom:200px;
    }
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bbpw33db/16/

Comment: How can I center the text caption? It seems that It can be centered. Any idea?

Comment: Change the top css property to an appropriate value so the text is centered. Currently top: -15px;. Increase or decrease this value so the image is centered exactly. I already set the top -15px.

Answer (score 0):

Your slide div is larger than your image

so change .slide width to 260px

```
.slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 260px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 20px;
    border: 3px solid red;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbpw33db/12/

Comment: How can I center the text caption? It seems that It can be centered. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you looking for:

```
   .top {
       width: 100%;
       height: 100%; 
    }
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z3ga06g6/).

Regards.